# Parse XML document without a parent node - JAVA

Tags: java, xml, file, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that needs to be parsed to output the data of an element. However, the file doesn't have a parent node and the conventional way to parse XML files is giving me this error:

> The markup in the document following the root element must be
>   well-formed.

**XML File:**

```
<row>
    <dam>bellair dam</dam>
    <last_year>70.6</last_year>
    <fsc>4.3</fsc>
    <latitude>33:42:43</latitude>
    <river>brak river</river>
    <last_week>35.9</last_week>
    <this_week>35.9</this_week>
    <longitude>20:35:52</longitude>
</row>
<row>
    <dam>berg river dam</dam>
    <last_year>52.7</last_year>
    <fsc>127.1</fsc>
    <latitude>33:54:25</latitude>
    <river>berg river</river>
    <last_week>37.3</last_week>
    <this_week>38.2</this_week>
    <longitude>19:3:30</longitude>
</row>
<row>
    <dam>brandvlei dam</dam>
    <last_year>38.0</last_year>
    <fsc>286.1</fsc>
    <latitude>33:42:42.88</latitude>
    <river>lower brandvlei river</river>
    <last_week>20.7</last_week>
    <this_week>20.5</this_week>
    <longitude>19:25:7.85</longitude>
</row>
```

Is there a way to parse the data in the XML file as string and use string manipulation to work on it? Because the conventional way of parsing the file is not working. Plus I cannot change (add) a root node to the XML file. Or how about writing the data to a text file?

Example of output:

```
Enter name of the data file:
testdata.xml
The dams are:
bellair dam
berg river dam
brandvlei dam
```

Comment: You shouldn't call your file an XML file, because it is obviously not well-formed. Why don't you create a temporary file with a root node and the contents of your original file? Then you can use every standard XML parser to parse that file.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the contents because that's the file I was given. And my program will be tested against this type of file. But there's no alternative to get the contents except for using DocumentBuilder etc. which is not working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a malformed XML you will have a few options. You can either modify the input, write your own parser or partially parse each row as an xml.

A suggestion:

```
File file = new File("malformedXmlMissingRoot.xml");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
List<InputStream> streams = Arrays.asList(
    new ByteArrayInputStream("<root>".getBytes()),
    fis,
    new ByteArrayInputStream("</root>".getBytes()));
InputStream cntr = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(str));
```

and use that `InputStream` in your typical XML parser.